# populate based on condition in mongoose js not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 schema

```
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var DeviceSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    code: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    os: {
        type: String
    },
    userEmail: {
        type: String
    },
    checkoutTime: {
        type: Date

    },
    tags: {
        type: [String]

    }

});
module.exports = DeviceSchema;

var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var TrackHistorySchema = new Schema({
    userEmail: {
        type: String
    },
    device: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Device',
        required: true
    },
    checkinTime: {
        type: Date
    },
    checkoutTime: {
        type: Date,
        'default': Date.now
    }

});
module.exports = TrackHistorySchema;
```

I have a search track history with criteria user email id and device name.

This works if I used on email criteria from history table

```
TrackHistory.find({'userEmail': req.query.searchText})
                    .populate({path: 'device'})
                    .sort('-name')
                    .skip(page * maxHistoryPerPage)
                    .limit(maxHistoryPerPage)
                    .exec(next);
```

But it will not work if I used device name criteria from device table

```
TrackHistory.find({})
                    .populate({path: 'device', match: {name: req.query.searchText}})
                    .sort('-name')
                    .skip(page * maxHistoryPerPage)
                    .limit(maxHistoryPerPage)
                    .exec(next);
```

I am getting all rows of history with device columns null, just like a left join in mysql. I wanted an inner join like functionality, that is if device name not matching then the corresponding history rows also should not be shown. I tried different combinations from mongoose documentation. Tried where clause also.

I am using mongoose 3.6.2 (latest available as of now)

## Edit - adding model code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var DeviceSchema = require('../schemas/device');
var Device = mongoose.model('Device', DeviceSchema);
module.exports = Device;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TrackHistorySchema = require('../schemas/track_history');
var TrackHistory = mongoose.model('TrackHistory', TrackHistorySchema);
module.exports = TrackHistory;
```

Comment: Can you show the model initialization aswell please? It is important that you call your reference the name of your model, not the schema as in DeviceSchema.

Comment: I have edited and included the model initialization.